# The optimal setup for Remote Desktop Access for Windows Server with MS office for multiply users

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop-services, rds, microsoft-office, microsoft

I need to setup Remote Desktop Access for multiply users (up to 10 users) with MS Office accessible for all users.

I already have:

- Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Licence (1 License)
- Microsoft Win Rmt Dskt Svcs CAL 2008 (10 Licenses)
- Microsoft Windows Server CAL 2008 (25 Licences)
- Mircosoft Office Licences (10 Licences)

What would be the optimal configuration?

Of course, I want to minimize costs and maximize simplicity. But simplicity is more important as far as I am not professional DevOps and I did not work a lot with windows eco system in general. I am generally technically experienced, though.

What hosting service should I use: AWS, Azure of smth else?

Do I need to buy any more licences?

Comment: If you really have Remote Desktop 2008 licenses, they are probably expired by now... But if they are 2008R2 then you're fine. At least, from what I saw, all my 2008 licenses expired and washed away like I never had them.

Comment: Otherwise, I don't see you need to buy anything else. But I can't really answer you as I don't know what is the best cloud service, I have no idea/experience/desire to run RDP in the cloud.